# Why StringObject' s method chars() returns string's char[] as a u2*

Tags: android, dalvik

Blow is the definition of struct StringObject in dalvik/vm/oo/Object.h

```
struct StringObject : Object {
/* variable #of u4 slots; u8 uses 2 slots */
u4              instanceData[1];

/** Returns this string's length in characters. */
int length() const;

/**
 * Returns this string's length in bytes when encoded as modified UTF-8.
 * Does not include a terminating NUL byte.
 */
int utfLength() const;

/** Returns this string's char[] as an ArrayObject. */
ArrayObject* array() const;

/** Returns this string's char[] as a u2*. */
const u2* chars() const;
};
```

How can I use StringObject to print the actual string? I have tried and cannot get the string from method chars().

And, why  StringObject' s method  chars()  returns string's char[] as a u2* ?

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dalvik encodes string in utf-16 because JAVA use utf-16 to encode string.  and there is a method called convertUtf16ToUtf8(...) in file dalvik/vm/UtfString.cpp, converting utf16 string (u2* ) to utf8 char *.

Answer (score 0):

It is a utf-16 encoded string, so each code unit is 16 bits. Hence the u2*.

Comment: how could I print this to the system log? I use ALOG(LOG_WARN, .. ."%s"...),  but just get the first char of the string.

Comment: UTF-16 and UTF-32  encodings encode small codes with nul bytes, so they cannot be printed by printf in C.  So why Dalvik encodes string in utf-16?

Comment: Thans very much!  and I have find the answer. Dalvik encodes string in utf-16 because JAVA use utf-16 to encode string.  and there is a method called convertUtf16ToUtf8(...)  in file dalvik/vm/UtfString.cpp, converting utf16 string (u2*) to utf8 char *.